# Global replacement in c# for javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript

i want to perform a global replacement equivalent code in c# for java script code below

```
text=text.replace(/-/g, '');
```

How can i do that?

Global replacement in javascript actually means this

```
var str="Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
var n=str.replace(/blue/g,"red");

Mr Blue has a red house and a red car
```

Comment: The javascript code should be `text = text.replace(/-/g, "")`

Comment: yes true you are but what for c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text = text.Replace( "-", "" );
```

Does global replacement, as shown in the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The `output` will contain the updated string.

`string output = Regex.Replace(text, "-", "");`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
text = text.Replace("-", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = s.Replace("scary", "not scary");
```